# Can we delete records in batches without their respective ids in spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to the spring boot and currently working on project in which I want to delete records in batches without considering their respective ids. I've created the following table named `domain_stats`.

```
CREATE TABLE `domain_stats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domain` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `device_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `no_of_visits` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `domainDeviceVisits` (`domain`,`device_name`,`no_of_visits`)
);
```

I want to delete records of domain_stats table in batches using spring boot, but batches should be comprised of list of records containing value for domain, device_name and no_of_visits column, but will not consider id value. Also, we have unique key for domain, device_name and no_of_visits.

**Domain Stats Entity Class**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name="domain_stats")
public class DomainStats {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "domain", columnDefinition = "varchar(255)", nullable = false)
    private String domain;

    @Column(name = "device_name", columnDefinition = "varchar(255)", nullable = false)
    private String deviceName;

    @Column(name = "no_of_visits", columnDefinition = "int(4)", nullable = false)
    private Integer noOfVisits;

}
```

**DomainStatsRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface DomainStatsRepository extends JpaRepository<DomainStats,Long>{
   
}
```

**DomainStatsDTO**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class DomainStatsDTO {
    private String domain;
    private String deviceName;
    private Integer noOfVisits;
}
```

**DeleteStatsController**

```
@RestController
public class DeleteStatsController {
    
    @Autowired
    private DomainStatsRepository domainStatsRepository;

    @DeleteMapping("/delete")
    public String deleteStats(@RequestBody List<DomainStatsDTO> domainStatsDTOs){
        List<DomainStats> domainStats = domainStatsDTOs.stream()
            .map(req -> {
                DomainStats dStats = new DomainStats();
                dStats.setDomain(req.getDomain());
                dStats.setDeviceName(req.getDeviceName());
                dStats.setNoOfVisits(req.getNoOfVisits());
                return dStats;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        domainStatsRepository.deleteInBatch(domainStats);
        return "Deleted Successfully";
    }
}
```

When we call the /delete api with following json body, then it should all records in batches without fetching ids related to the records.

```
[
    {
        "domain":"cnn.com",
        "deviceName":"Mobile",
        "noOfVisits":100
    },
    {
       "domain":"fb.com",
        "deviceName":"Desktop",
        "noOfVisits":100
    }
]
```

Comment: You can create a `@Query` with `DELETE FROM ... WHERE id in :ids)`. I think it fetches the IDs in order to have the entities in the session.

Comment: In first glance i think that first of all you have to replace this line in table annotation. @Table(
    uniqueConstraints=
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"domain", "string", "device_name", "string", "no_of_visits", "number"})
)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a `delete` query in an `@Query` annotation.

But since you don't seem to really utilise JPA in this case I would consider stepping one step down in the stack of abstractions and use straight JDBC via `JdbcTemplate`